# Google Chrome Interferes with Copy and Paste in Excel

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste

I have got the following problem: Copy (Ctrl+C) and Paste (Ctrl+V) function in Excel 2010 does not work (or acts weirdly) if I have Google Chrome opened at the same time.

This issue is Excel-specific meaning that in Word or Powerpoint copy/paste works fine. It is also Chrome- and CoolNovo-specific as the copy/paste in Excel does not interfere with other internet browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have Excel 2010 and Chrome open at work just about every day, and I've never experienced any problems. Perhaps you could clarify what "acts weirdly" means in your circumstances, and what steps you have taken?

Comment: I also had exactly the same problem when Chrome was open. With the workbook open, shut down Chrome and the functions work again, start it up and they fail e.g. copying formulae.. really weird.. but at least it's not just me. There is a suggestion in another forum that the same issues occur with Firefox.

Comment: OK... (1) After (Ctrl+C) the selected cells are not highlited (no stripes are flickering around them). (2) The paste options icons after right-click are limited to the "Keep Text Only" option. When I click on "Paste Special" I am given only Past As: "Unicode Text" and "Text" options. @PDE: yes, when I close the browser everything comes back to normal...

Comment: Solved! It's apparently Skype Click to Call application. I have disable it and everything is back to normal. Cheers, guys for your suggestinons :)

Comment: @Dan If you found a solution, please [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and accept the answer.